# Should I always provide default value in php for TEXT fields in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I try to insert a new record in a table using Eloquent ORM included with Laravel Framework the insert statement resulted is as follows:

> INSET INTO `table_x` (`field_x`, `field_y`, `field_z`) 
>   VALUES (0, 1, 2)

I receive the following error from MySQL Server:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'field' doesn't have a
>   default value

I do not provide the field in my INSERT statement. The field is of type TEXT and from MySQL docs: **"BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values"**.

So I always have to provide myself a default value in my php code for TEXT fields? Or maybe should Eloquent take care of this and set an empty string automatically on insert?

Comment: Please give your table schema

Comment: Please add your fill and save code of the model in your controller. Maybe you should add a default value for your empty fields in your model.

Comment: I added in my model the default value using: protected $attributes = array(
  'field' => ''
);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL does not support having default values in TEXT columns. So you have to manually tell Laravel/MySQL what to put in that column. For example.

```
INSERT INTO table_x (field_x, field_y, field_z, your_text_field) VALUES (0, 1, 2, "");
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table_x (field_x, field_y, field_z, your_text_field) VALUES (0, 1, 2, NULL);
```

So in your Eloquent model, you'll have to do something like.

```
$myModel->your_text_field = '';
```

or

```
$myModel->your_text_field = null;
```

Depending on whether you have set your column to be nullable or not.

---

**Update:** As [Mihai Crăiță](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2147774/mihai-cr%c4%83i%c8%9b%c4%83) the question author commented in my answer, and [in GitHub ticket](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2265), we can set a default for any columns in the Eloquent model this way, so we don't need to worry about having to set manually all the time.

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent
{
    protected $attributes = array('your_text_field' => '');

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks! I added in my model the following array: 
protected $attributes = array(
  'field' => ''
);